# MongoDB query documents

Tags: mongodb

I am new to the MongoDB. Now I am using Mongo Shell Version 2.6.6. When I am reading the read operations using the db.collection.find(), I have also found the read operations db.collection.find({}) and db.collection.findOne(). What are the cons and pros using this read operations.

Comment: What is your insight? Did you look into the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its clearly stated in documentation of mongodb:

[find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)
[findOne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

`.find()` returns **ALL** documents that are mathing the query result, whereas `.findOne()` returns only **ONE** document, even if query matches many (it will return first object found)

In applications, difference has additional practical aspect - `findOne()` returns just an single json object, while `find()` retuns array of jsons, even if its one json found (it will be array with one json)

Comment: The **db.collection.findOne()** method also performs a read operation to return a single document. Internally, the **db.collection.findOne()** method is the **db.collection.find()** method with a limit of one.  #Select All Documents in a Collection.#
  An empty query documents({}) selects all documents in the collection.    **db.collection.find({})**  Not specifying a query documents to the **find()** is equivalent to specifying an empty query document.     Therefor the following operation is equivalent to the previous operation.  **db.collection.find()**

Comment: You overthink things. `find()` == `find({})`, and `findOne()` == `findOne({})`. `findOne()` returns just first found document, and can be compared to limit 1 sql operation, but here it also doesn't return array (so its not internally just limit to 1, but also different output format), but single object. All is explained clearly in mongodb docs.